# RCP Application how can we increase default height of Cool bar in ActionBarAdvisor

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am working on customization of an existing RCP application. Is there a way to increase the default height of the cool bar. I have tried below code but does'nt work:

```
 IToolBarManager toolbar = new ToolBarManager(SWT.FLAT | SWT.RIGHT);
        ToolBarContributionItem item = new ToolBarContributionItem(toolbar, "main");

        item.setCurrentHeight(5);
        item.setCurrentWidth(5);
        item.update(ICoolBarManager.SIZE);
```

Is there a way to do it using CSS? Below is the screenshot of what client wants exactly:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround to achieve this is to add icons of bigger size. I achieved what I wanted by adding icons of 64 by 64 pixels